# Laravel route dependent on user roles

Tags: routes, laravel-5.3, roles, middleware, laravel-middleware

I am using middleware to get roles for a user.

The problem is, is with how i want to use routes. I want each user to be able to go to `/dashboard` and it knows what role they've got and send them down the correct route.

I can see after debugging that the first route is getting ignored in favour of the last route so if the user isn't an admin, they get an error message saying insufficient privileges.

Is there a way i can adjust my middleware or routes so any user can go to `/dashboard` and get the route related to their role?

Routes.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    // User Dashboard
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard-user', 'middleware' => 'roles', 'roles' => ['user'], 'uses' => 'DashboardController@user']);
    // Admin Dashboard
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'dashboard-admin', 'middleware' => 'roles', 'roles' => ['admin'], 'uses' => 'DashboardController@admin']);
});
```

CheckRole.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() === null) {
            return response("Insufficient permissions", 401);
        }

        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;

        if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return response("Insufficient permissions", 401);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        ...
        ...
        'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class
    ];
}
```

Comment: Looking to do something similar, do you manage to find a solution? I tried to use Auth::user() in my routes file and then require a set of admin routes or user routes but Auth::user() is not set even though I am logged in

Comment: A bit late but I use Laratrust